# Laravel 5.5 Partitioning a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, partition

How eloquent model mapping to partition table, for example table 1 and table 2...

I don't know if this is the correct solution.

```
$user = new User();
$user->setConnection('table_001');
$user->name = 'Joe';
$user->save();
```

I want the Table to be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> 
PARTITION BY RANGE (month) ( 
  PARTITION 01 VALUES LESS THAN (201601), 
  PARTITION 02 VALUES LESS THAN (201602), 
  PARTITION 03 VALUES LESS THAN (201603), 
  PARTITION 04 VALUES LESS THAN (201604), 
);
```

Is it possible?
Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want to save a new data to a database or update an existing data?

Comment: @NabilFarhan I'm going to migrate a new Table. Is it possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add comments to clarify. Put everything in one place. Also include the code of what you've tried so far, as a [mcve]. You may want to take the [tour] first.

Comment: I incorporated @user2430745's last comment into the question.